# MVC3 <authentication> and <authorization> inside a <location> attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am new the .NET and MVC3 and I am currently in the middle of converting a long standing Classic ASP site into a MVC3 Application site.

The same site has four areas where I would need unique login pages and discrete levels of access and security. This means I do not want to use the default code in my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Instead, I'd like to be able to set up Areas inside of my application and then use the `<location>` attribute to set up Authentication and Authorization rules for each. So for example:

```
<location path="AreaName">
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/AreaName/Login" timeout="15" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

If I remove these three lines:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/AreaName/Login" timeout="15" />
  </authentication>
```

Then when I try to access any of the views on in the path "AreaName" I get redirected first back to ~/Account/LogOn. If I put those three lines back in, I get the following error:

> **Parser Error Message:** It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. 
>   This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured
>   as an application in IIS.

I have searched against this error and none of the suggestions made seem to apply. I have seen one answer where the logic should be put on the controller instead of in the web config, but those methods still imply that you are going to use the default `<authentication>` for the entire site.

I don't understand why I can't have an `<authentication>` property inside of a `<location>`. Any help on this would be most appreciated.

I apologize if I have worded any of this question incorrectly.

Comment: It seems this is because in the Machine.config file for the ASP.NET framework, the setting of `allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"` is set for the authentication section. So I guess my question becomes, is there a way to over-ride that setting in the machine.config and set it to say `allowDefinition="Everywhere"` in my applications web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need a custom membership provider and a custom role provider (if needed)...here is an example post [Custom membership providers in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers)...If your concern is level of access you will need to use a Custom Role provider...

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my question, I'm not interested in having everything funnel through a single login page - I want to be able to eventually have unique login pages for each of the areas that are protected. The final step still shows having the `[Authorize]` directive applied to individual actions in the controller.

Comment: ok...my next question is why you need to have multiple login pages...when you could have membership roles...say for example if you have an admin area...you need not have a login page seperately for an admin...you can still use the same login page...but this time you will add the admin role to the user identity...and your authorize attribute will look like  [Authorize(Roles = RoleNames.Admin)]...this way you can use one login page...

Comment: I am not building a site from scratch - the four areas each have their own user databases and inside three of those areas there are functions accessible to users and admins - and an admin of one area is not an admin of the second area or the third. These databases can not be merged or altered, nor do I have the luxury of scrapping them and starting with a brand new database. Why can't I just employ unique authorization at the location level?